# Verbose GLSL Shader compile on Intel

Tags: opengl, shader, glsl

I have a project that uses GLSL shaders.

This project is designed not to print anything to stdout unless something is going wrong or you explicitly turn on some extra debug output.

When a shader compile fails the log length given by `glGetProgramInfoLog` is >0, and sometimes when it succeeds its >0, and gives compile *warnings* instead. When you have a shader that compiles perfectly the log length is <1... this is how it works on my NVidia card on my dev machine.

For my sins, I also do some dev on a laptop with an intel integrated graphics card. The code runs fine, but whenever I do a shader compile the log contains:

"shader was successfully compiled to run on hardware"

Which is very annoying, as I now have no way to decide if I should print the string out, apart from some sort of string analysis, eg:

```
strstr("successfully",log)
```

Hopefully its obvious why that's undesirable.
How, if at all, can I tell if a message is worth printing out using the OpenGL api?

EDIT:

If I use `glGetShaderiv(shaderobj,GL_COMPILE_STATUS,&err);` then I don't get compile warnings, only errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go:

```
glGetShaderiv(shaderobj,GL_COMPILE_STATUS,&err);
if(!err) { /* now print out the error log */ }
```

This is the only compile status you get; there isn't any portable way I've found to determine if you've got warnings. (The compile log can be full of whatever the implementation cares to put in it, including notification of success.)

Comment: So, you want to know if there are warnings, or errors, but not success messages? Sorry, I'm pretty sure that compile status is all there is.

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I want.
Shame, I guess I'll have to do it the messy way.
Thanks.

Comment: @DaedalusFall So I think you got your answer to be accepted, as you asked how it's possible and Jay replied **correctly** that it isn't (although in a comment).

Comment: Fair point, I left it open in case someone came along with a solution. I've accepted the answer but Jay, maybe you could edit the answer to include what is in your comment?